# Docker desktop stuck on pulling image

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, docker-engine

So I want pull hello-world image to test the docker desktop, so I switched the docker context into `desktop-linux` via 'docker context use desktop-linux', but the problem is the  pulling progress is never finished (stuck). what should I do, my internet connection is great so I think is not the internet connection.

Maybe the problem is on the docker context (docker endpoint to be exact) because the default (the main one) is fine at pulling docker image, but somehow when I switch to docker desktop context, the image pulling process stuck

btw here's the docker endpoint

default: `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`

desktop linux: `unix:///home/unkn0wn/.docker/desktop/docker.sock`

What should I do so I could pull image from docker desktop too?